# Error creating bean with name 'db' defined in file [...]: Instantiation of bean failed (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, spring

Originaly, we've had `@Service` and `@Repository` on single class (called `DbHome`), doing just CRUD operations. Each operation was mrked `@Transactional`, which is obviously slow.

So I want to move `@Transactional` to the class (called `Db`) where are more logical operations (like, `getUsers`, or `getDevices`). But I've read that `@Transactional` can only be used in `@Service`. So I moved `@Service` from `DbHome` to `Db class`.

But now I get the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'db' defined in file [/home/pitel/tomcat/wtpwebapps/anna_controller/WEB-INF/classes/cz/master/anna/controller/dao/Db.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [cz.master.anna.controller.dao.Db]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1093)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [cz.master.anna.controller.dao.Db]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cz.master.anna.controller.dao.Db.<init>(Db.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 24 more
```

The start of the `Db` class:

```java
@Service
public class Db {
    public static synchronized Db getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Db();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    private static Db instance = null;
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    private DbHome dbHome = null;
    private Db() {
        dbHome = (DbHome) ControllerConfig.getInstance().getAppContext().getBean("dbHome");
    }

    // Normal methods are here

}
```

And the `DbHome` class:

```java
@Repository("dbHome")
public class DbHome {
    @Autowired(required=true)
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    // CRUD methods are here
}
```

I'm new to the Spring stuff, so can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NullPointerException` occured at 
`ControllerConfig.getInstance().getAppContext().getBean("dbHome")`

Check that your application context is not `null`.

The best practice is, don't create instace on application context inside constructor create it using `@Autowiring`.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is here:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;
```

This bean appContext is not going to initialize until and unless this (DB) object is fully constructed and you are trying to access it from constructor and hence you end up with null pointer exception.

If you need to run some initialization code, you should pull the code from constructor into a method, and annotate that method with [@PostConstruct](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations)

Comment: There is still something wrong... I've changed the constructor to this:

@PostConstruct
 private void getDbHome() {
  dbHome = (DbHome) ControllerConfig.getInstance().getAppContext().getBean("dbHome");
 }

and I still get the error.